# Acer Aspire Aoa110 won't start

Tags: acer-aspire

I have a Acer Aspire Aoa110 mini laptop without a  CD drive.I have tried starting it but it wont start,can i use the usb port to recover my data?.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have enough detail for a good explanation (when you say it won't boot, do you mean it does not turn on at all, or is Windows hanging?).  If Windows won't load, then the short answer is yes.  You can easily create a bootable USB drive and boot to that instead of a CD.

Comment: It don't even show anything,just a blank screen.

Comment: In that case there is something wrong with the hardware (hard drive, motherboard, video, etc).  If it's under warranty you can probably get it fixed for free by calling Acer.  If not, you can bring it into an authorized Acer repair place and have them take a look at it.  Good luck!